# Where to find the nifty Textbox with the grayed out instruction?

Tags: .net, wpf, textbox

While logging in to msn-messenger you have these nifty textboxes that show you what to type (username, password) in gray text. Once you start typing it disappears. This surely is not hard to implement using a user control in WPF, but is this control/behaviour already available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called a "watermark textbox".  Here's a code sample:

http://vistasquad.co.uk/blogs/nondestructive/archive/2009/01/02/wpf-textbox-with-watermark.aspx

Comment: I found the code in Arkain's example hard to grasp.
Your link provides an effective and simple to extend WatermardedTextBox. I integrated it in my code. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Not that I'm aware, but I haven't spend much time with SL3 yet, but [here](http://bendewey.wordpress.com/2008/09/27/wpf-shadowed-textbox-watermark/) is an article of how to implement it.